# iOS 10 App XPC connection interrupted (Works fine in simulator)

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10, xpc

We just updated to swift 3 and are trying run code for ios 10. Everything was working fine, but now we have encountered an interesting error. The code works find on the simulator, but when we try to build to the device, when switching between views the following error occurs:

2016-10-11 23:04:23.574944 Glancer[6526:2174852] XPC connection interrupted
2016-10-11 23:04:23.575269 Glancer[6526:2174950] [Common] Terminating since there is no system app.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you use a specific segue programatically as opposed to dragging on the `Main.storyboard`? Because that is what the issue sounds like

Comment: @KSigWyatt We don't use segues, we have a tab view controller. Any more ideas?